# Why aren't helper methods in Rails available to be used in tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial book and on chapter 8 you have to write a test to see if the user is logged in. The book says helper methods aren’t available in tests. So while we have the method

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end
```

we instead have to use session method and write the test like

```
def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
end
```

Comment: Have you tried including the helper module in the test? Something like `include ActionView::Helpers`  may work

Comment: I should point out though, that even if my suggestion does work, it probably isn't wise to do so... The reason for probably not using helper methods in tests, is because if the helper method is broken it will break the test... And it may be difficult to distinguish if the thing your testing is broken or if it's the helper method you're using that's broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include helper methods directly into the tests, but it would be really messy and would get you into many problems later.

Helper methods are available to the controller instance. You can use the controller (or some other object that includes the helper) to call that method.